# Set a date from today as the difference between 2 other dates

Tags: php, date

I'm calculating the difference between 2 dates

```
$diff = abs(strtotime($result2["expiry_date"]) - strtotime($result2["start_date"]));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
```

But I want to set a new variable (`$new_date`) as the difference between the 2 dates above.

For example,

```
$result2["expiry_date"] = '2018-03-06'
$result2["start_date"] = '2019-03-06'
```

The difference is 1 year

so, `$new_date = '2020-03-06'`

Essentially, I need to set the `$new_date` which is the new `expiry_date`.

So I need to work out the time between the current start and expiry date, then add that same period to `expiry_date` to get the new expiry date

Comment: Your new_date makes no sense. How does a difference of 1 year mean the variable should be 8 years shy of the earliest date and 9 years from the latest?

Comment: @Trent apologies, typo in my `$new_date` var

Comment: check my update, hopefully that makes a bit more sense?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the code to generate that new variable? What is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the date diff to the start date

```
 $date2='2019-03-06';
    $date1='2018-03-06';


    $timeDiff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

    $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

    $numberDays = intval($numberDays)+1;

    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2. " + $numberDays days"));
```

**OP:**:

```
2020-03-06
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that complex function if you're just using date strings

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2017-03-06');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2018-03-06');
$datetime3 = $datetime2->add(new DateInterval('P' . $datetime1->diff($datetime2)->y . 'Y'));

echo $datetime3->format('Y-m-d');
```

This only works if the difference is in years, but you can just as easily change that DateInterval to a different diff value (month, days etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
$result2["expiry_date"] = new \DateTime('2018-03-06');
$result2["start_date"] = new \DateTime('2019-03-06');

$diff = $result2["expiry_date"]->diff($result2["start_date"]);
$newDate = (new \DateTime())->add($diff);
var_dump($newDate->format('Y-m-d'));
```